# How to join 5 tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a minor problem with SQL Server, I have five tables:

- `Klientet` (ID_Klienti (PK), Emri, Mbiemri, Adressa, Qyteti, Telefoni)
- `Punetoret` (ID_Puntori (PK), ID_Lokacioni (foreign key), Emri, Mbiemri, Adressa, Qyteti, Telefoni)
- `Lokacioni` (ID_Lokacioni (PK), Emri_Lokacionit)
- `Veturat` (ID_Veturat (PK), Modeli, Viti, Ngjyrat)
- `Shitjet` (ID_Shitja (PK), ID_Klienti (FK), ID_Puntori (FK), ID_Lokacioni(PK), ID_Vetura)

I want to inner join or (join) all five of them, and I get a result with 47 rows instead of number between 4 and 10. I've done it but it is missing something and I can't find what. I hope you guys can help me .

This is where I got so far

```
SELECT 
    Klientet.Emri, Klientet.Mbiemri, 
    Punetoret.Emri, Punetoret.Mbiemri,
    Lokacioni.Emri_Lokacionit,
    Shitjet.Data_shitjes
FROM 
    Klientet 
INNER JOIN 
    Shitjet ON Shitjet.ID_Klienti = Klientet.ID_Klienti
INNER JOIN 
    Punetoret ON Punetoret.ID_Punetori = Shitjet.ID_Punetori
INNER JOIN 
    Lokacioni ON Lokacioni.ID_Lokacioni = Punetoret.ID_Lokacioni
INNER JOIN 
    Veturat ON Lokacioni.ID_Lokacioni = Veturat.ID_Lokacioni      
WHERE 
    Emri_Lokacionit = 'Prishtine' 
    OR Emri_Lokacionit = 'Gjilan' 
    OR Emri_Lokacionit = 'Mitrovice'
```

Comment: Can you try adding a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) example and also your desired output?

Comment: please give sample data to understand your question.

Comment: Just a tip - you can use where Emri_Lokacionit in ('Prishtine','Gjilan','Mitrovice')

Comment: Are the 47 rows you are getting, the same? Do you have a one to many relationship between two tables, that are duplicating the rows? In that case just add "DISTINCT".

Comment: I think you didn't posted table structure correctly. Where is `Veturat.ID_Lokacioni`? In join you specified that *Lokacioni.ID_Lokacioni= Veturat.ID_Lokacioni*